Why i cannot search a site column which is of type Single Line of text?
I have a site content type which contains those site columns: -

This content type has been used in around 10 custom lists. Now I can search by all the fields without any issue, except for the "SALES ORDER#" which have this internal name "SALESORDER".
For example, there are items with those values: -

here is the search result when search by the ITEM#: -

or by the PO #:-

while for the SALESORDER# I will get zero result: -

I checked the Search service, and I found this managed property: -

and this crawl property: -

the site and lists have been created around 1.5 months ago, and at that time i requested site re-index.. any advice why the SALES ORDER# field is not searchable?
Here is the Search schema for a field name Commodity which is searchable, and which mimic the setting for the SALES ORDER#: -

+

so not sure what is going on for the SALES ORDER# field?

You should manually map your managed property on an empty refinablestring property, and she must be mapped on Crawled property : "OWS_your column name"(internal name not the display name)
and in your search bar type : OWS_your column name:your text search*


i do not think this is the case, s the managed properties created automatically will not have any mapping to crawl properties (this is the behavior for the other site columns and they are searchable), check the Commodity field for example or any other field you will see the same, but they are searchable...
